# iOS Programing: How to save skins purchased with tokens

Tags: ios

Long story short; my friend and I are developing a small game. In this game, users can purchase tokens with actual money, and use those tokens to purchase skins/characters in our game. We have no issues keeping track of their in-app purchases; however, we are having a hard time figuring out how to save the skins that they purchased and have it displayed across all devices that they are playing the game on (we currently are using iCloud to share data such as high score, number of coins, etc to their other devices).

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: You may need to use an SQL database for this. This way you can make requests to your database that stores what skins users have purchased.

Comment: Backend implementation for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are already saving data to iCloud, I would recommend having your skins stored as an array of id's in the cloud.

So if you have 10 skins available, and they buy the 5th and 8th, save an int array with 5,8 to the cloud.

The problem here is if they delete the app on all devices it will be hard for them to recover their skins, however they should be able to restore their in-app purchases and get the tokens back, and then re-buy the skins if they want to.

Comment: The way I have it set up now, is that things like high score, total coins, are saved in iCloud. We have tested it so when the user deletes the application, iCloud will restore that data.

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/63269/how-to-save-your-game-data-tutorial-part-2-of-2 . This is the tutorial I was basing my work off of; however, I can't seem to figure out how to make it work with arrays. Could you possibly point me in the right direction?

Comment: @dmouawad this link has a pretty good tutorial for adding an array to iCloud https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-icloud-key-value-storage--pre-37542

Comment: I appreciate the link, I will definitely check it out and report back!

Comment: It seems to work out! I've got the array saving in iCloud now, thank you so much!